# Find Memory Usage of Admin

Tags: admin, memory

I have seen tips which show you how to display the memory usage of your website. This usually involves adding php code to your website theme's function.php file.

However, I am looking to display the memory usage in the admin, not on the front-end website.

How can I display the memory usage of the wordpress admin from within the admin?

Answer (score 2):

The easist way is the plugin [WP System Health](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-system-health/), great plugin and works fine. Alternativ you build a function and hook in wp-admin; example admin_footer

Comment: Not tested, but it looks like that the [http://webjawns.com/tpc-memory-usage-for-wordpress/ TPC! Memory Usage for WordPress] (Wordpress Plugin) keeps track/history of maximum value(s). At least a related plugin as well.

Comment: a new alternative, small and fine, this plugin: https://gist.github.com/1204323